# Alt + Tab (switch windows) and Alt + Shift (switch languanges) stopped working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

A couple of days ago, some keyboard hot keys, such as <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> (switch windows) and <kbd>Alt + Shift</kbd> (to switch keyboard input languages) stopped working.

Some notes/considerations:
- If I change "switch input language" hot key to <kbd>Ctrl + Shift</kbd> - it works.
- Using right <kbd>Alt</kbd> doesn't help.
- I don't remember that I had installed or updated something right before this problem occurred.
- About 5-7 days I moved my system from HDD to SSD drive using Norton Ghost. But hot keys worked for first days after moving the system.
- I tried rebooting in safe mode.
- I tried closing as many processes as possible.
- I tried the AltTabFixer application (which has something to do with fixing invisible always-on-top zero size windows).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys work ok when used separately.
- I have an up to date antivirus (Avira) working in real-time mode. Disabling it doesn't help also :)
- People in the Internet sometimes advice disabling Aero Theme, it doesn't help me.

This one may be important I think:
- I've tried to connect a PS/2 keyboard (my default one is USB) and after a couple of restarts <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> was still not working. Then I changed "switch input language" hotkey back to <kbd>Alt + Shift</kbd> and language switching and, even more interesting, <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> started to work! After returning to my default USB keyboard the hotkeys don't work again.

Comment: Logitech keyboard or mouse? Uninstall setpoint.

Comment: BTC keyboard, Genius mouse.

Comment: Does either have special software installed, especially that does any binding? Either disable or uninstall it for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your participating in our brainstorming, but no, no special software for keyboard or mouse installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, After 2 days since I posted this question, I noticed that Alt + Tab is working again. I tried changing "switch input language" hot key back to Alt + Shift and it is also working. Very weird...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the language is downloaded in your computer as follows:

time and language-> language->preferred language-> add a preferred language.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).